# Drupal call user_profile_form in profile_kit edit page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am sorry for my poor English.
I'm grateful I have the answer.

I work in Drupal to do the following:
Edit User Page Fields (change password) in the Profile Settings page to show that can be edited all at once.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right and you are trying to update the password for all the users then you should have a look at the `users` table. Be careful not to change the users that have the `uid = 0` (anonymous user) and `uid = 1` (the super-admin user).

So if you want to change the password for all the users run the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `pass` = MD5('your_new_password_goes_here') 
WHERE `uid` NOT IN (0,1)
```

The above query will update the password for all the users except the anonymous user and the super-admin user. I'm not sure why you would want to reset the password for all the users, but  hope it serves you well :)